# Java syntax: parenthesis before lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I've seen that code in Google's [example code](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy):

```
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
        this,
        params,
        (OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener) () -> {
          // TODO: Load and show the consent form.
        },
        ...
```

I guess interface name (OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener) before the lambda is for readability, but what semantics of that - type casting lambda to that interface or what?

Comment: It might not be for readability, it might be necessary if there are multiple overloads of `requestConsentInfoUpdate` which each have three parameters where the first two are the same type, and the third parameter of each is a functional interface which is type-compatible with the provided lambda. In that case you have to add a cast to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's true in general, but in this case there is only one overload of [requestConsentInfoUpdate](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/api/reference/com/google/android/ump/ConsentInformation.html#requestConsentInfoUpdate(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.ump.ConsentRequestParameters,%20com.google.android.ump.ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener,%20com.google.android.ump.ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected in your question, this is a simple type casting of the lambda. The lambda is itself an implementation of [`OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener`](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/api/reference/com/google/android/ump/ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener), so this would be equivalent of an expression like

```
(List<Integer>) new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

As if it's for readability or is it because the compiler struggles to infer the type, it's hard to say it without the full context. It being an example, I would lean toward extra information to help the reader understand what interface they are implementing here. Do you have a link to that example?

Comment: added link to the question

Comment: I confirm it really looks like it's just to tell the reader what is the type of the lambda parameter. BTW looks like this type is very similar to `Consumer<Void>` though.